# Bash array cannot return correct values in pipe while loop

Tags: bash, shell

I want to process the file names with the whitespace, in steps: firstly `ls` them, then `read` the outputs one by one in the proper delimiter, then do else things. I know I have many different commands can be chosen, like `find . -print0`, or by changing `IFS`, but, specifically, on this matter, it seems that I have encountered a **shell bug** that I cannot figure out.

To reproduce:

```
# make a new empty folder
mkdir mytest
cd mytest

# create two files, one file name has the whitespace
touch 'nice 1' good
```

Create a new script file, the contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash

# to deal with filename contains whitespaces by using `array'
filetxt=()
ls | while read i; do
    if [[ -f "$i" ]]; then
        filetxt+=( "$i" )
        
        # debug, inside works well
        for ((t=0; $t<${#filetxt[*]}; t++)); do echo "-->${filetxt[$t]}<--"; done
        echo '========='
        echo ">>${#filetxt[*]}<<"
        echo ''
        echo ''

    fi
done

# empty?? bug, cannot be dealt with
echo "last:   >>${filetxt[*]}<<"
```

As my comment, can anyone please explain to me why `${#filetxt[*]}` is empty outside the `while` loop? Yet, inside it, the code works well.

Is it due to the using of `|` (pipe) in the head of `while` loop, however, for `bash`, except from specifically defined, any variable will be in `global` status, thus, it should have contents stored in `filetxt`.

Moreover, my bash version is `5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, I greatly appreciate for your help, many thanks.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Also, [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend. It’ll tell you about a number of issues, including why `$filetxt` is empty.

Comment: @Biffen, thanks for your comment, I have seen the post that you shared with. With the `ShellCheck`, I guess I have found the problem, just like I thought, this problem is due to the subshell: `^-- SC2030 (info): Modification of filetxt is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).`

Comment: Your `while` loop runs in a subshell and the variables in a subshell cannot affect the variables of parent shell. Read [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

Comment: If you will not use a subshell, then replace `command | while read x; do; ...; done` by `while read x; do; ...; done <<< "$( command)"`

Comment: Here you can replace `ls | while read i; do ...` by `for i in *; do ...`